# Convex conjugate of a function of sum of norms

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization

I am trying to find the conjugate of function $f(x) = \|x\|_2 + \frac{1}{2} \|x\|_2^2$   i.e.,
$f^*(v) = \sup_x (v^Tx - f(x))$ where $x  \in\mathbb  R^n$

Although $f(x)$ is convex, I am stuck as the function cannot be directly differentiated. I know how to find convex conjugate of norm function using dual norm but I cannot apply it here. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: It can, actually, be differentiated everywhere except at the origin:
$\nabla f(x) = x \cdot ( 1/\|x\|_2 + 1 )$

Answer (score 3):

Since the function is radially symmetric, so is its conjugate. So you can as well consider the one-dimensional problem, with $f(x)=|x|+x^2/2$. Recall that the gradient of conjugate function is the inverse of the gradient of $f$.

Again by symmetry, it suffices to consider  $x>0$ only. 
Since $f'(x)=1+x$, the inverse is defined only for $x\ge 1$. Imagine that the discontinuity of $f'$ at the origin "stretches" the origin into $[-1,1]$, which the gradient of the conjugate $f^*$ will collapse back into a point. So, $(f^*)'(v)=(v-1)^+$ which integrates to
$$f^*(v) = \frac12((\|v\|-1)^+)^2 $$
As usual, $a^+=\max(a,0)$.

Comment: This is great, but I think there is a factor of 2 error: $f'(x)=1+x$.

Comment: This is interesting. Thank you very much. One clarification, the norm $||v||$ is 1-norm $||v||_1$ or 2-norm $||v||_2$ ? As 1-norm is not radially symmetric, I assume it should be 2-norm. Right ? Also is it possible to know where the supremum is achieved i.e., $x$ ? For $||v|| \leq 1$, I understand $x = 0$. But for other values ?

Comment: @SohilShah The norm is $2$-norm, the only norm that appeared in the question. The supremum is attained at the point where $\nabla f = v$, which is the point $(\nabla f^*)(v)$.

Comment: @Behaviour Thanks. Got it.